# HttpEntity ClassNotFound?

Tags: java, apache

hi im trying to use apatche 4.0.1 using the post methode [in this example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java) but i got HttpEntity ClassNotFound exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correclty including the httpcore jar into your class path.  Are you running it as a jar, webapp or just application via some IDE?

Edit:  Based on your comment.

ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Thats your culprit.  Im assuming httpcore uses LogFactory and you are not including it in your classpath.  Look for commons-logging.jar and include that in your classpath as well.

Comment: via Eclipse IDE, i import the the Jar Files to the project and the IDE recognize HttpEntity when i write it after the import.

Comment: And youre running it as a "Java Application" through eclipse?

Comment: Yes, i running it as Java Application .

Comment: even when i declare just 
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
i got this exception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: i included commons-logging-1.1.1.jar and it works , thank you so much.